# How to uncover columns of matrix in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I have the following beamer frame, which has a matrix with 4 columns. The point is that I want to uncover the columns one by one, and additionally somewhere above where one column ends and other one starts I want to put a small text and under the text a sign, something like "TEST \\ $\approx$" (where the red lines are shown below). Any ideas how to do these in TikZ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,
    positioning,
    ext.node-families,
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Enc}   {Enc} % instead of \mathsf{Enc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PKey}  {PKey}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sim}   {Sim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prover}{Prover}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intuition}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners, node family/width=samewidth},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{aligned}
\& 
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{aligned}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\& \text{too small} \& \text{to read}
\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't ask for multiple things in one post. Always focus on one problem per question. How to add annotations is not related to uncovering columns.

Comment: @Zarko Why remove the tikz-pgf tag? This question is pretty much about how to use some environments from tikz, so making sure that tikz users will see this question sounds like a good idea (the special tags tikz-styles and tikz-matrix are probably not as well monitored as the more general tikz-pgf tag).

Comment: Well, you vere revert my editing, so no problem here anymore :-).  To my opinion, `beamer` is the main point (it enable uncovering of things) and then Ti*k*z `matrix`, however you may be more right than me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `overlay-beamer-styles` library you will have access to the `visible on` key that accepts a typical beamer overlay specification.

For the nodes, we simply use the `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` count, for the text above the columns we simply use an undrawn path between the north east and north west corners. With the `calc` library you could also specify

```
 at ($(m-1-1.north east)!.5!(m-1-2.north west)$)
```

for the nodes.
I'll put this in a nice loop so you only have to change the list.

For this, we need to give the matrix a name (here `(m)`) and then each cell is available as `(m-<row>-<column>)`.

As an alternative, I've added a `tikzcd` solution where `north connect` uses TikZ-CD's option to select the anchors. The `path only` makes sure that no line is actually drawn. TikZ-CD comes with its own `phantom` style but that does change the placement of the nodes along the path again.

### Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,
    positioning,
    ext.node-families,
    overlay-beamer-styles
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Enc}   {Enc} % instead of \mathsf{Enc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PKey}  {PKey}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sim}   {Sim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prover}{Prover}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intuition}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners,
    node family/width=samewidth,
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn->},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{aligned}
\& 
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{aligned}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\& \text{too small} \& \text{to read}
\\};
\path[nodes={align=center, above}] 
  foreach \Text[count=\col from 2] in {
    Test\\$\approx$, Whee\\{$(2, 3)$}, Last\\One} {
    (m-1-\pgfinteval{\col-1}.north east)
     -- node[visible on=<\col->] {\Text} (m-1-\col.north west)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Intuition}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tikzcd}[
  north connect/.style={path only, start anchor=north east, end anchor=north west, r},
  cells={nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners,
    node family/width=samewidth,
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn->
  }},
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm, column sep=.2cm, arrows=-, labels={font=},
  labels={math mode=false, align=center}]
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{aligned}
          \arrow[north connect, visible on=<2->, "Test\\$\approx$" visible on=<2->]
\& 
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{aligned}
          \arrow[north connect, visible on=<3->, "Whee\\{$(2, 3)$}" visible on=<3->]
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{alignedat}
          \arrow[north connect, visible on=<4->, "Last\\One" visible on=<4->]
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\& \text{too small} \& \text{to read}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library to uncover the matrix column wise:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,
    positioning,
    ext.node-families,
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Enc}   {Enc} % instead of \mathsf{Enc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PKey}  {PKey}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sim}   {Sim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prover}{Prover}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intuition}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  nodes={draw=\bcol, fill=\fcol, rounded corners, node family/width=samewidth, visible on=<\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn->},
  matrix of math nodes,
  ampersand replacement = \&,
  row sep=.1cm,
  column sep=.2cm] {
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{aligned}
\& 
\begin{aligned} c_0 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                c_1 & \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
          \pi_{t^*} & \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{aligned}
\&
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Prover(t^*, x, w) \end{alignedat}
\& 
\begin{alignedat}{3} & c_0 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
                     & c_1 && \gets \Enc(\PKey_1^{\mathsf{PKE}}, m_0) \\
               & \pi_{t^*} && \gets \Sim(t^*, x) \end{alignedat}
\\
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\&
\mathsf{sk}_{f, t} = iO(\text{PKey}[\mathsf{sk}_0^{\mathsf{PKE}}, t])
\& \text{too small} \& \text{to read}
\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]